# How can I get full name in a single scanf/gets in C language?

Tags: c, string, for-loop, structure

I am creating a C program using `structure` in which I take input of 10 employee information and print it. I'm using `for loop` for taking input.

But I'm unable to take the name of the next employee if I use space in between, like this:- **JAMES WILLIAM** (Imaginary name), But if I  write **JAMES** or **JAMES_WILLIAM** it will take input of the next employee name.
I have tried `scanf("%s", &emp[i].name)` and `gets(emp[i].name)` but the same problem is repeating.
You can find my entire program [here](https://github.com/Yashraj2502/Employee/blob/main/Experiment19.c).

Would greatly appreciate any tips!
Thanks for the help!

Comment: `scanf()` stops reading on whitspace. `gets()` will stop reading on newline, thus it can read in values that have whitespace in them, but [it is dangerous](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gets-is-risky-to-use/) to use. Use `fgets()` or `getline()` or equivalent instead.

Comment: While `scanf` is okay for simple things when starting out, once things start to get a bit more complicated it's not really enough by itself. As mentioned the POSIX (Linux and macOS) function [`getline`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) is a good way to read a line. Or the C standard [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) function.

Comment: Don't use `gets`. It's broken by design and dangerous.

Comment: While you should not use `gets`, it should have read a full line, spaces and all. So it should definitely not have the same problem as the `%s` format for `scanf`. *Unless* you enter one name per line, in which case you need to read two (or more) times.